# PHP file corruption when downloading .jpg files?

Tags: php, filesize

When downloading .jpg files via a URL on my site, the file becomes corrupt. I haven't tested a lot of files bu t.pdf's download fine. I'm seeing the following error in the file:

**b>Warning:  filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for sunny.jpg in **/home/content/91/4761691/html/pages/download.php** on line **89****

Line 89 is the filesize() function as seen below...

```
$ID=stripslashes($_GET['recordid']);
$file = $_GET['file'];
// the absolute path to your directory storing your files.
$path = '../photos/' . $ID . '/';
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$file.'"');
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));   <========== line 89
readfile($path.$file);
```

Any ideas on why this is failing and how to address?

Comment: What's the value of `$path.$file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing `readfile($path.$file);` to output the file, so I assume that you should also write `filesize($path.$file);` to get the file size of the same file.

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path.$file));
readfile($path.$file);
```

Comment: That looks like it got it, thank you! 

Is there a reason my browser thinks the file is a .wav file by default but opens with an image viewer application? My file association is set for an image viewer application...

Comment: It could have something to do with the Content-Type you are propagating (`application/force-download`). Try giving the appropriate content type here.